# How do I fix my loop for verifying a valid response?

Tags: python

when i run this code, and i input an invalid response, it works perfectly fine by asking me to input a valid response.

But when i input an invalid response and it asks me to input again and I input a valid response, it doesn't break the loop.

How do I fix this?

```
def plchoice():
    global choice
    global plchoice
    plchoice = input("Rock, Paper, Or Scissors: ")
    while plchoice not in ["rock", "Rock", "Paper", "paper", "Scissors", "scissors"]:
        print("Invalid Choice! Pick Again.")
        choice = input("Rock, Paper, Or Scissors: ")
```

Comment: You set choice, but check if plchoice is correct

Comment: Functions are objects too, and `plchoice` starts as a variable pointing to the function. But because you used `global plchoice` and use `plchoice = ...`, you are replacing the function with a string value. If you try to call `plchoice()` again, you'll get an error, because strings are not callable.

Comment: ok so I set plchoice = ...   to plchoiceq = ...   and I also changed choice = input(...) to plchoiceq = input(...) in the while loop. This was able to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't break out of the loop because you never change the value of `plchoice`, you are setting the value of `choice` in the loop.

Also, using global variables is not pythonic. Consider having the `game_over()` function have the arguments `(plchoice,cpchoice)`.

If you edit the plchoice and cpchoice functions to return their values rather than setting the globabl value, you can then change the `game_going()` function to:

```py
def game_going():
    game_over(plchoice(),cpchoice())
```

Comment: Why are you trying to call `plchoice()` and `cpchoice()`? They are not functions. Also, the OP isn't using those names as inputs, they are *outputs*. They probably only need one value returned from the function, however.

Comment: They are functions (the edited version of the post took out the cpchoice function). The functions are not currently returning anything (so OP would need to edit that), but I wanted to try to push OP to think pythonically without rewriting the whole program for them.

Comment: Right, because the way you worded this (*Consider calling game_over() with the arguments `(plchoice,cpchoice)`* confused me there, as it's not consistent with the code sample.

Comment: Do point out that setting the `plchoice` global will also mean they are going to replace the function with something else. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I updated the answer to be a bit more clear. `game_over` function should take those two arguments, the two choice functions should return their values, and all the global variables should go away.

Comment: Your answer is more about solving an issue the OP hasn't asked about and doesn't really explain how to fix the question posed. Having said that it is likely to be a typo in which the OP has used the wrong variable

Comment: @Sayse, the first line solves the issue OP asked about. I was just providing some additional feedback to help make the code better.

Answer (score 0):

```
def plchoice():
choice = input("Rock, Paper, Or Scissors: ")
while choice.lower() not in ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]:
    print("Invalid Choice! Pick Again.")
    choice = input("Rock, Paper, Or Scissors: ")
print("Choice is :", choice)
```

U first take the choice value from the user.. And you run the while loop continuously until the value of choice is one among the expected value.. The while loops terminates as soon as the expected value is entered..

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.